# (Solved) Intonation Problem (Only with High E and B Strings) in Acoustic Guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, maintenance, intonation, lutherie

My **Acoustic** Guitar's Intonation is right in place for the bottom 4 strings, But the Top two are off. Octave is 50 Cents flat in B-string and 1 semi-tone flat in E-string.

-

- I thought it was the Truss Rod, but only the top two strings are out of Intonation. So I thought I'd first get advice from MusSE than getting the fretboard messed up.
- I read up other questions in MusSE which said using different Gauge Strings might affect this. The problem is that I don't exactly remember the gauges. G is from a 0.13 Set and Everything else is From another set (Same set) and that Gauge is 0.12, 0.13 or 0.14. Since these numbers don't vary a lot, I'm thinking Gauge is not the problem here.
- Will doing anything to the Bridge Saddle be a solution. If yes, What to and How to?

-

Please Help. The Strings fairly new and I'd prefer to not take them off. Should I do anything to the Bridge Saddle? Or Should I put on all the Strings from the same set as G taking off the old strings? Or Is there a different solution?

Please don't close the question saying it has to be focussed, The only issue I have here is that the top 2 strings are not in right intonation and I'm listing all the observations I've made.

**Edit**: One common thing answers have suggested is going for a higher gauge at E and B. But I want to let you people know that I'm already at 0.12 to 0.14 Range. Is it plausible to go higher? with a Semitone Flat Octave?

Just in case this might help shape the answer more in context. The place where I am is on a LockDown for COVID-19 right now, So I can only wait or Do something with the existing things.

**Edit 2: [Solved, thanks to Tim]** Two things (See comments in Tim's answer for more detailed version) -

1. Truss Rod, It was a Horrible Upbow, So anyone reading this for having a similar problem must **check their Truss Rod First**
2. **String Height at Peghead/Tuner Post** was too high up. Strings by design have to leave the peghead at a point very close to the neck's wood which affects effective length of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intonation will only ever be exactly right when the saddle on the bridge has been adjusted for the particular string in question. Put a different gauge string there instead, and the intonation will be out. Change by .001" and you'd prbably shrug shoulders and live with it.

Whilst frets (generally!) are all parallel to the nut, the line across the saddles never can be. That's why Leo came up with separate saddles on his Strat, and Mr. Gibson used his 'Tunamatic' bridge. Even the three saddles on Teles didn't solve the problem - I had to re-profile mine for intonation on the top two strings.

Your top string being a semitone out at fret 12 means either the string isn't suited to the saddle position, or the saddle position isn't suited to the string gauge. Being *flat* means the saddle is way too far back - string's too long. If the bridge is fixed, it'll be a luthier job, so initially, I'd be going for a heavier gauge string, but that might need to be getting on for twice the diameter of the existing one. You may be going from, say, .009" to .014" - only a guess!

The second string is generally longer than the first, so maybe change for a slightly heavier gauge for that will suffice.

Comment: Should I go to a higher gauge? Because I was doubting I got too high... Will sending a picture of the saddle help? I'm already at 0.13 Gauge, so is it better to do a modification in the saddle?

Comment: Try to ascertain what gauge the guitar had originally. Yes a pic may help.

Comment: Also, You said Saddle's too far back (towards the pins side) which makes the effective length of string long. So Tell me if this is correct, I can also say "The saddles is too high which causes Longer Effective Length". I can't move saddle position but can (I've never done this before, I consider this risky) Sand Paper the saddle. Ill include a pic in the original question, Thanks.

Comment: Sanding the saddle to make it shorter will alter the action (height of the strings above the fretboard) and could cause other problems. Changing string gauges can help, but your instrument seems really far off, you may not be able to solve this completely just by changing gauges. Potential solutions for this will depend somewhat on the shape/style of saddle you have on the instrument now. A photo would definitely help.

Comment: Sanding the saddle will NOT solve the intonation problem.

Comment: I changed Gauges long before I started noticing these intonation problems though. Does this have anything to do with how I let the Guitar lean against the wall unlike others who get a stand or wall hang?

Comment: That's about the worst way to leave a guitar - apart from letting the kids use it as a bat! It won't have helped. Check the neck for straightness.

Comment: Neck Straightness is the same as Truss Rod right? I'll check Truss Rod once again, Maybe I didn't do it properly (this is the first time I'm doing all this)


Would You like to take the last to comments and include in your answer? I really think this got me closer to the answer and It'll be great if you could just quote these or include in some way the last two comments.

Comment: The truss rod is used to *adjust* the straightness of the neck. Look down the neck, and the strings (which are dead straght) should be *roughly* the same parallel from end to end. How high will depend on personal preference. But if the distance is say 2mm at the nut and 6mm at the last fret, you've got problems! The comments won't go away!

Comment: Is it possible that a Bent-Neck causes just the two strings to go out of intonation?

Comment: Seems like you will be better off taking it to a luthier, who will diagnose and offer a solution. Over sites like this, it's almost impossible.

Comment: Im adjusting Truss Rod right now, It was very off. I don't know how I missed it the first time. Rod's too Loose. Yes If I'm not able to solve this (I'm not gonna touch the saddle, I'm afraid). Ill take it to a Luthier. Thanks.

Comment: B is 30 cents flat now and I think I’m approx. 7.5 deg away from a slight relief. Ill try going further.

Comment: Also bear in mind tat if the guitar is rarely played above, say, the 7th fret, it'll be near enough in tune at the lower ones without drastic action.

Comment: E is fixed now. B is not yet there. For B alone unlike other strings, the place where string starts off from the peghead is high up the peghead. Does this make a difference?

Comment: On the bridge, it should be the same as the others, but further away from the fretboard. If you mean the nut end, rewind the string so it's lower on the tuner post.

Answer (score 1):

Saddle position to obtain correct intonation depends on several variables - gauge and tension of the string, and action. Strings that are heavier, tighter, and higher typically need a saddle that's farther back to get the intonation correct. String style can impact intonation as well - wound strings typically need different setup than plain wound strings, for instance.

On a modern electric guitar, intonation is easy, since you can move the position of each string saddle independently. This adjustment isn't possible an acoustic guitar, which can lead to issues with instruments that are not well set up. Generally, if you know the string gauge and style that was originally on the instrument, staying with those choices will give the best results - an instrument built with heavier strings in mind will be hard to set up with really light strings, and so on. String gauge choice can impact other aspects of setup besides intonation (namely action, relief, and nut slotting) so regardless of intonation, it's best to stick with a given type and gauge of string unless you're willing to do a complete setup on the instrument.

But if you have an instrument that isn't intonated even with the "right" strings (or, at least, with the strings you want to use), all hope is not lost - you can still obtain some range of adjustment by modifying or replacing the bridge saddle. Most saddles are cut straight - the top edge of the saddle tapers to a gentle point that's usually on the center of the saddle. However, the width of the saddle provides some degree of adjustability - if the top edge of the saddle is shaped to slope towards the front or the back, you can effectively move the point at which the string breaks over the saddle forwards or backwards. Saddles shaped like this are called **compensated saddles** and they can be bought ready-made, or cut from a saddle blank. The following photo shows two straight cut saddles (the top two) and two different compensated saddles (the bottom two):

[image: compensated saddles]

You can find compensated saddles online, pre-made with different strings compensated towards the front or back of the saddle, depending on your needs. Even if your guitar already has a compensated saddle, you may find that a different saddle with the strings in different positions may help.